# beamer with title in citation

Tags: beamer, bibliographies, citing

I am using beamer and writing my bibliographies with `\bibliographystyle{apalike}`. It shows the authors and the year on my citation `\cite{cloudGrid:6}`:

> [Ian Foster, 2008]

I would like to show also the title on my citations. Is it possible on beamer?

> [Ian Foster, 2008, Cloud Computing and Grid Computing 360-Degree Compared]

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be easily done using [`biblatex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) and its `\citetitle` command:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\newcommand\mCite[1]{[\cite{#1}, \citetitle{#1}]}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test frame}
As mentioned in~\mCite{almendro}...
\end{frame} 

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\bibname}
\printbibliography
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]